# Haskell Cabal: How to ignore dependencies

Tags: haskell, dependencies, cabal

I'm trying to install a package (nymphaea as it happens). This depends on an earlier version of base than the one I have. I'm not keen on downgrading my base libraries, so I'd like to try to just ignore that dependency, and see how things go.

Is there a way to tell cabal to miss out a particular dependency?

Update: After I edit the cabal file, what do I do with it? Cabal doesn't have an obvious way to point it at a file, nor anywhere I can manually put cabal files, as far as I can tell.

[As per below, apparently I should just invoke `cabal install` in a directory containing the edited cabal file ]

Update 2: Unfortunately, cabal gives me a weird error about package versions being required which I appear to have:

```
$ cabal install -v --upgrade-dependencies time
Reading available packages...
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed:
time-1.2.0.5 (new version)
Extracting
C:\Users\Marcin\AppData\Roaming\cabal\packages\hackage.haskell.org\time\1.2.0.5\time-1.2.0.5.tar.gz
to C:\Users\Marcin\time-1.2.0.54736...
Creating C:\Users\Marcin\time-1.2.0.54736\time-1.2.0.5\dist\setup (and its
parents)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2011.2.0.1\bin\ghc.exe --make C:\Users\Marcin\time-1.2.0.54736\time-1.2.0.5\Setu
p.hs -o C:\Users\Marcin\time-1.2.0.54736\time-1.2.0.5\dist\setup\setup.exe -odir C:\Users\Marcin\time-1.2.0.54736\time-1
.2.0.5\dist\setup -hidir C:\Users\Marcin\time-1.2.0.54736\time-1.2.0.5\dist\setup -i -iC:\Users\Marcin\time-1.2.0.54736\
time-1.2.0.5 -package Cabal-1.10.1.0
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package Cabal-1.10.1.0:
    Cabal-1.10.1.0-55f781465ee9f32289755ad706c71f0f is unusable due to missing or recursive dependencies:
      directory-1.1.0.0-3a2367d72569467a8af8a231656ff1b8 process-1.0.1.5-b3dded8e54a2e13d22af410bdcfafff4
    (use -v for more information)
World file is already up to date.
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
time-1.2.0.5 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To follow up on the comments to Don's answer:

First, grab the package from Hackage.

```
$ cabal unpack nymphaea
```

Then edit the .cabal file and change `base <= 4.1.0.0` to `base > 3 && < 5`.

```
$ cd nymphaea-0.3
$ vim nymphaea.cabal
```

Now, try to install it.

```
$ cabal install
```

I got it to work with this change using Haskell Platform 2011.2.0.1 on Ubuntu Natty after installing the required Debian packages.

Comment: Thanks - however for me it still doesn't work because of another cryptic error (apparently time won't build because it depends on packages that I appear to already have?!?)

Comment: @Marcin: Hard to tell without seeing the error message, but most of the time such errors are caused by missing non-Haskell packages, or that the compiler is unable to find them. I had to install `libglade2-dev`, but there might also be other dependencies that I already had installed.

Comment: @Marcin: I remember having a similar problem with the `time` package before after upgrading it by accident. I ended up just reinstalling the Haskell Platform.

Answer (score 4):

You must edit the .cabal file associated with the package and remove any constraints on base that you see. Change, for example,

```
base < 3
```

to

```
base >= 3 && < 5
```

And see if it compiles. If it works, you might bump the version and let the maintainer know. If they don't respond, you might upload the fixed version to Hackage yourself.

Comment: This is the actual line from nymphaea.cabal: `build-depends:       base<=4.1.0.0, random, containers, mtl, parsec, glib, gtk>=0.10.0, glade, cairo`

Comment: Yeah, that's just wrong, since it depends on minor revs. Try `base > 3 && < 5`

Comment: What's wrong? That's a copy-paste from the actual file included when you download it.

Comment: Oh wait, are you saying that kind of base is wrong to depend on minor revisions? That makes sense.

Comment: OK, thanks, but one more question - where do cabal files live / what do I do to cabal to make it pay attention to my new file?

Comment: I've tried putting the new cabal file in AppData/Roaming/cabal/packages/ and AppData/Roaming/cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/ to no effect.

Comment: Couldn't the process of testing and notifying the maintainer be automated? I think it would be very useful, especially when new versions of GHC come out.